# syso insertion shortcut not working in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm currently running the latest version of Eclipse (2020-06, I believe) on MacOS Catalina. I am unable to use the shortcut where you type `syso`, then press Control+Space, which results in the text being replaced by `System.out.println()`. I have also tried `Syso`, `sysout`, and `Sysout` to no effect. I have checked my keybind preferences and Control+Space is bound to the content assist command. Further, if I do type `syso` and press Control+Space, I get a box saying "No Default Proposals". If I continue pressing it, this message changes to "No Template Proposals", then "No SWT Template Proposals", then "No Chain Template Proposals", and finally "No Java Proposals" before cycling back to the original message. Identical behavior is also seen with `sysout`, `Syso`, and `Sysout`. This occurs with the default preferences in Content Assist and Content Assist>Advanced. A reinstall didn't fix this issue.

I am aware of other topics dealing with the same issue. However, I tried the approaches mentioned, none of which worked.

Update: This is quite odd. Upon creating a new file, the shortcut works. I'm not sure what the difference was between the new file and the old one. Both were standard .java files.

Comment: Have you tried `sout` ?

Comment: @Pankaj I haven't, but trying it now would probably work, since `syso` works as well now. The issue mysteriously disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

From content assist>advanced> check Java proposals. (Eclipse IDE Enterprise Java and Web Developers - 2022-12). For the first time, it might not work. Create a new class and use CTRL+Spacebar. The suggestions will show up